# Abstract class extend Thread

Tags: android

**First question:**

How can we use

`ActivityManager activity =(ActivityManager)getSystemService(ForegroundApp.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)`

And also 
`getPackageManager` in a class that extends Thread?? I'm trying to fetch the Foreground activity's package name, its start time and end time in the foreground. I know this is Context based but I need to run this is in a thread.

**Second Question:** 
How can we call an abstract class that extends thread in a service??

This thread only runs when the screen is ON. So, I'll be registering for Screen ON and OFF intents in a service. In this service, when the screen is on, i need to call this Thread.

Example:

```
abstract class A extends Thread {

   abstract method met();

     public void run() {
      //Find out foreground's app name and its start and end time.
    }
}

  class B extends service {
    //Here i need to call A.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you have to do is simply pass an reference to your Activity in first case to class A, and reference to class A to class B. Easiest way is to pass by constructor.

```
abstract class A extends Thread {
    protected Activity activity;

    public A(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    abstract method met();

    public void run() {
      // activity.yourmethods()
      //Find out foreground's app name and its start and end time.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide me to start this abstract thread?? Cant use usual way since this is an abstract, it cant be instantiated.

Comment: You need to extend your abstract thread (by creating new class) and implement abstract methods, like met(). Also, is it necessary to A class be abstract?

Comment: Yes, because, this foreground activities list which I'm fetching must be reused in every other classes in which i extend A. I'll call this abstract method met() in void run(), which hits the execution in every class where met() method is implemented.

Comment: I need to run this thread every second. My intention is that, once this thread starts running, in turn it must call all met() methods implemented in classes which extends A.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian, your method of passing Activity worked fine for determining the foreground's activity. Please help me to start this abstract class A from an Activity...

Comment: As I said, you can't. You have to make class C (public class C extends A) which will implement met() method. I'm not sure if we understand each other: http://pastebin.com/8Vu7it11